# how to compare arrays and return difference php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I retrieve all databases in phpmyadmin in server1 and call that $array1. I also retrieve all databases in phpmyadmin in server2 and call that $array2.

Now I want to compare the two arrays and return the difference, but I get an error "array to string conversion" here is my code:

```
$db = new MysqliDb ('');
$db->setHost('server1');
$array1=$db->rawQuery('SHOW DATABASES');

$db = new MysqliDb ('');
$db->setHost('server2');
$array2=$db->rawQuery('SHOW DATABASES');

$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

echo'<pre>';    
print_r($result);
echo'</pre>';
```

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Comment: Please, provide sample output of `var_dump($array1)`.

Comment: Most likely it's because `$array1` and/or `$array2` are multidimensional. `array_diff` only works on 1-dimensional arrays, casting all values in the arrays that are compared to strings. See the [notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#refsect1-function.array-diff-notes) on the manual page of `array_diff`.

Comment: this is how my array looks like  and gives an error where i do the array_diff
Array 
 (   [0] => Array
        (
            [Database] => test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Database] => test1
        )
)   the var dump looks like this 
 array(2) { [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(5) "test2"
  }

Comment: this is how my array looks like  and gives an error where i do the array_diff
Array 
 (   [0] => Array
        (
            [Database] => test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Database] => test1
        )
)   
the var dump looks like this 
 array(2) { 
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(5) "test2"
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got a solution..   array_diff does only works with normal arrays so i broke down my nested arrays then used array_diff and it worked

Answer (score 1):

An Option would be to use `array_udiff()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php. And create the function needed for your arrays. (Can't help you without any info on the arrays)

Comment: this is how my array looks like  and gives an error where i do the array_diff
Array 
 (   [0] => Array
        (
            [Database] => test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Database] => test1
        )
)   
the var dump looks like this 
 array(2) { 
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(4) "test"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Database"]=>
    string(5) "test2"
  }

Answer (score -4):

try in_array() function in php
  reff: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: How does `in_array` compare two arrays? That function is only useful to check if a given value is available in an array.

Comment: yes that function is only for checking given value if available in array